# How do I get a particular feature branch from origin?

Tags: git, github

I've moved on to a new machine.

I have set myself up on my new machine like so;

```
git clone -b develop git@github.com:example/example.git example
```

That gives me;

```
develop
master
```

On my old machine I had created feature branches and pushed to the repo.
A `git branch` on my old machine will look like;

```
develop
feature/ecommerce-one
feature/ecommerce-two
feature/ecommerce-three
master
```

How do I get those feature branches on to my new machine?
Either all at once or one at a time. I'm not bothered.

I tried `git clone https://github.com/example/example.git --branch feature/ecommerce-one --single-branch` but within the current directory so it just re-created the whole project within a new directory on that directory.

Comment: `git clone` already copies all of the branches from origin. If `git branch --remote` on your new machine doesn't list the feature branches, then they don't exist in the origin repository and you probably never pushed them from your old machine to the origin.

Comment: `git branch --remote` nice tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get those feature branches on to my new machine?

You have to push your branches to the origin in order to get them on a different machine

```
git push origin <b1>
git push origin <b2>

...
```

Once all you branches in the remote you can do a fetch on your new machine:

```
// The fetch will update your local repository metadata with the content of
// the remote repository so you will be able to checkout your branch as 
// local branch 
git fetch --all --prune

//git checkout <b1>
```

[image]

---

#### Git basic worflow

[image]

Comment: I had already tried `git checkout origin <branch name>` on my new machine and that didn't work. I was not expecting `git checkout <branch name>` to just work straight off the bat but it did. Thinking about it now, it does kind of make sense.

Comment: But you have to push your branches first to origin of course.

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, did you push your branches on your old machine to the remote repository? You can check by calling `git branch --remote` and verifying that all your branches are there first.

If they are not, you have to push them to the remote like so:

```
git push origin <localBranchName>:<desiredRemoteBranchName>
```

Once they are up, you can just fetch them on the new machine.

Comment: Yes, I did push frequently on my old machine. And they're on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

After cloning from from github, your `origin` is set to github repo. So you run `git fetch origin` and then all branches on github repo are now on your new machine too, but under `origin/` namespace.

To copy them as local (normal) branches, run `git checkout -b mybranch origin/mybranch` for all those branches.

If you don't remember the branch names, run `git branch -r`